# RegEx captures file extension when I only want the base name

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following RegEx in a Mod-Rewrite command, but don't want the $1 variable to capture include the .html extension.

```
RewriteRule ^photo-search\/([^/]+)(/|\.html|)$ http://www.artminds.com/cgi-bin/ImageFolio4/imageFolio.cgi\?search=$1&bool\=all [H=cgi-script]
```

This command works exactly as intended for the following URL's
http://www.artminds.com/photo-search/outdoors  is rewritten to capture "outdoors" and properly sends just the word "outdoors" to the variable n my rewrite code.
http://www.artminds.com/photo-search/outdoors/ also captures just the word "outdoors" and inserts it without the trailing slash in my rewrite code.

But if someone enters /photo-search/outdoors.html the file extension .html gets included in the rewrite code, which triggers a soft 404, because outdoors.html is being passed through to the cgi script, and of course it doesn't find a keyword that ends with .html.

I've tried various options, but my error logs either show File Not Found or it merely passes through only "photo-search" and not the portion that follows "photo-search".

Thanks in advance.

Art Minds
Pasadena, CA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fix is to make the `[^/]+` part *non-greedy*, so that it will prefer to match as little as possible as long as the regex as a whole still matches. That way, it won't include the `.html` (since the `.html` can be matched by a later part of the regex). To do this, use `+?` instead of `+`:

```
RewriteRule ^photo-search\/([^/]+?)(/|\.html|)$ http://www.artminds.com/cgi-bin/ImageFolio4/imageFolio.cgi\?search=$1&bool\=all [H=cgi-script]
```

However, I'm wondering whether you really want this rule to be applied at all to a URL that ends in (say) `.jpg`? If not, then a better fix is probably to include `.` in the list of characters that the `[^/]+` part isn't allowed to match:

```
RewriteRule ^photo-search\/([^/.]+)(/|\.html|)$ http://www.artminds.com/cgi-bin/ImageFolio4/imageFolio.cgi\?search=$1&bool\=all [H=cgi-script]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Your first option worked unless there was no trailing slash.  However, I modified it by adding and additional "|" or option as follows:

Comment: Thank you @ruakh for the solution. It works perfectly now.  I don't see the possibility of needing the second option with a possible .jpg extension, but wouldn't the `.` in the list of excluded characters need to be preceded by a \ to indicate its literal value, and not the special character `.` ?  Now, would you know how get the browser to continue to display the modified URL rather that showing the rewrite URL?

Comment: @ArtMinds: Re: "wouldn't the `.` in the list of excluded characters need to be preceded by a \ to indicate its literal value, and not the special character `.`": No, because `.` is not special inside a character class. The regex `3[.]4`, for example, is equivalent to the regex `3\.4`. Re: "would you know how get the browser to continue to display the modified URL rather that showing the rewrite URL?": To perform an actual HTTP redirect, rather than just doing the transformations internally, change `[H=cgi-script]` to `[R]`.

Comment: Thank you @ruakh I just tried changing `[H=cgi-script]` to `[R]` but the same result, showing the redirected URL, not the URL I typed in the browser address bar. My .htaccess file starts with this:    `Options +FollowSymLinks`
 `RewriteEngine on`
Is there something else that I need to make it happen by just using the `[R]`?

Comment: @ArtMinds: Re: "but the same result, showing the redirected URL, not the URL I typed in the browser address bar": Sorry, changing to `[R]` is how you *would* get the redirected URL -- I guess you want the opposite. Well, your rule, as written, should not cause a redirect. Is it possible that you have a different rule that would cause a redirect? Like, do you have any other `RewriteRule`-s?

Comment: Thank you for all your valuable help.  I've seen web sites that use what look like non-dynamic URLs that appear in search engines, and when you click those links, the URL doesn't display a dynamic URL in the browser, usually for searches, like you've helped me accomplish.  However, on those sites, if you conduct a search, then their dynamic URLs are revealed. Some others, it's still not revealed, but only a static-appearing URL shows in the browser.  Do you know how that is accomplished?

Comment: @ArtMinds: I think you should post your questions as a new question. This is well beyond the scope of "I [...] don't want the $1 variable to capture include the .html extension".

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 RewriteRule ^photo-search\/([^/\.]+)(/|\.html|)$
 http://www.artminds.com/cgi-bin/ImageFolio4/imageFolio.cgi\?search=$1&bool\=all
 [H=cgi-script]
```

Your $1 parameter matches the first group (between ()) but since the regex for that group says any character except / it also grabs the .html. By telling it to not accept .'s it will only take the string without the extension.

Comment: Thank you @Glenn-Vandamme for your help. Your solution works as does the one that follows. I will ask you also if you know how to then get the browser to display the URL as entered, and not display the rewrite that generates the page?